# How to reload datable client side with get request?

Tags: datatables-1.10

I have the following code

```
 $(document).ready(function(){  
    var url = "https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?format=json&q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.xchange%20where%20pair%20in%20(%22USDEUR%22,%20%22USDJPY%22,%20%22USDBGN%22,%20%22USDCZK%22,%20%22USDDKK%22,%20%22USDGBP%22,%20%22USDHUF%22,%20%22USDPLN%22,%20%22USDRON%22,%20%22USDSEK%22,%20%22USDCHF%22,%20%22USDNOK%22,%20%22USDHRK%22,%20%22USDRUB%22,%20%22USDTRY%22,%20%22USDAUD%22,%20%22USDBRL%22,%20%22USDCAD%22,%20%22USDCNY%22,%20%22USDHKD%22,%20%22USDIDR%22,%20%22USDILS%22,%20%22USDINR%22,%20%22USDKRW%22,%20%22USDMXN%22,%20%22USDMYR%22,%20%22USDNZD%22,%20%22USDPHP%22,%20%22USDSGD%22,%20%22USDTHB%22,%20%22USDZAR%22,%20%22USDISK%22)&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys";
    $.get(url, function( data ) {
    var ratesJSON = data['query']['results']['rate'];
  console.log( "Data Loaded: " + data['query']['results']['rate'].length );
   $('#example').DataTable( {
        data: ratesJSON,
        columns: [
            { data: "Name" },
            { data: "Rate" },
            { data: "Ask" },
            { data: "Bid." },
            { data: "Date" },
            { data: "Time" }
        ]

    } );
});

});
```

The above works just fine. However now I am required to reload the table (as well as the data) every 30 seconds. Can I use datatable reload to achieve it ? Or should I use jQuery to repeat the whole process ?

Comment: "what's the best way" is too broad. What have you considered? datatables is a module for a large javascript framework; i'm sure you can google something up.

Comment: Can I just use jquery and repeat the whole process ? or perhaps using datatable reload and restructure the code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working by restructuring the code into

```
 $(document).ready(function(){  
    var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
        //data: ratesJSON,
        columns: [
            { data: "Name" },
            { data: "Rate" },
            { data: "Ask" },
            { data: "Bid." },
            { data: "Date" },
            { data: "Time" }
        ],
        ajax : {
            url: "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?format=json&q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.xchange%20where%20pair%20in%20(%22USDEUR%22,%20%22USDJPY%22,%20%22USDBGN%22,%20%22USDCZK%22,%20%22USDDKK%22,%20%22USDGBP%22,%20%22USDHUF%22,%20%22USDPLN%22,%20%22USDRON%22,%20%22USDSEK%22,%20%22USDCHF%22,%20%22USDNOK%22,%20%22USDHRK%22,%20%22USDRUB%22,%20%22USDTRY%22,%20%22USDAUD%22,%20%22USDBRL%22,%20%22USDCAD%22,%20%22USDCNY%22,%20%22USDHKD%22,%20%22USDIDR%22,%20%22USDILS%22,%20%22USDINR%22,%20%22USDKRW%22,%20%22USDMXN%22,%20%22USDMYR%22,%20%22USDNZD%22,%20%22USDPHP%22,%20%22USDSGD%22,%20%22USDTHB%22,%20%22USDZAR%22,%20%22USDISK%22)&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys",
            dataSrc: function ( json ) {
                  return json['query']['results']['rate'];
            }
        }
    } );

    setInterval( function () {
    table.ajax.reload();
    }, 3000 );

});
```